# FORTRAN 90 MINVAL comparison error

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have a subroutine that doesn't behave as expected, and I cannot understand why.

```
SUBROUTINE CHECK_INPUT_2D(VNAME,X,MIN_VAL)
CHARACTER(LEN=*) :: VNAME 
REAL(KIND=JPRB),INTENT(INOUT) :: X(:,:)
REAL(KIND=JPRB),INTENT(IN),OPTIONAL :: MIN_VAL
LOGICAL :: L_MIN
CHARACTER(LEN=128) :: PRO_NAME='CHECK_INPUT_2D'
L_MIN= .FALSE.
IF (PRESENT(MIN_VAL)) THEN
    IF (ANY(X < MIN_VAL)) THEN
    L_MIN = .TRUE.
    WHERE (X < MIN_VAL)
        X = MIN_VAL
    END WHERE
   END IF
END IF
IF(L_MIN) WRITE(*,*) 'WARNING:'//PRO_NAME//'MIN VAL:'//TRIM(VNAME)//,MINVAL(X),' SET: ',MIN_VAL
END SUBROUTINE CHECK_INPUT_2D
```

The subroutine is called with MIN_VAL set to 0.0 but this routine still generates a warning. Why is this when no values of X are less than 0.0? How do I solve this bug?

This subroutine is located in a module with the following header:

```
MODULE MOD_UTILS
USE KIND1  ,ONLY : JPIM ,JPRB
IMPLICIT NONE

INTERFACE CHECK_INPUT
MODULE PROCEDURE CHECK_INPUT_1D,CHECK_INPUT_2D,CHECK_INPUT_3D
END INTERFACE
CONTAINS
```

and the subroutine is called from another module with the following header:

```
MODULE MOD_SIM

#include "defs.h"

USE MOD_SIM_TYPES
USE MOD_SIMULATOR
USE KIND1  ,ONLY : JPIM, JPRB

IMPLICIT NONE

CONTAINS
```

In MOD_SIM is the calling subroutine that simply contains: CALL CHECK_INPUT_2D(VNAME,X,MIN_VAL)

Appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Does this subroutine have an explicit interface defined where you are calling it from?

Comment: No, it does not. Should I add one? How does this causes/prevents this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use of `OPTIONAL` arguments requires that the calling procedure be aware of this.  The only way to accomplish this in Fortran is through the use of an explicit interface.

You procedure is within a module `MOD_UTILS` so it has an explicit interface. Make sure the procedure that is calling this subroutine has `use MOD_UTILS` or is using a module uses that module.

The need for the explicit interface is required by the standard:

1. Fortran 2008: 12.4.2.2 p1.(1)(2)(a) ISO/IEC 1539-1:2010
2. Fortran 90: 12.3.1.1 (2)(a) ISO/IEC 1539:1991(E)

Comment: Hmm...interesting reply. I'm not a good fortran programmer and I didn't write this code. I can only make small changes. It seems a bit strange that this declaration issue would cause the erroneous behavior in the subroutine. Therefore, I added more explanations regarding the module containing the problematic subroutine and the module containing the calling subroutine. I apologize for not being more specific. I had no idea where the error lie. Do you still think the calling module should include the interface?

Comment: I've added use MOD_UTILS to the calling subroutine but this doesn't help.
CALLING SIMULATOR...
----- WARNING: CHECK_INPUT_2D: MINIMUM VALUE OF SNOW_LS=>
  0.000000000000000E+000  SET TO:   0.000000000000000E+000